# What is FID and how does it works?

Tags: 7, files

I could not find a clear explanation about what is a 'fid'. I got is an identifier for file in drupal, but no more than that. How it is generated? Is unique for any file? When it is used and why? Could someone give a clear explanation of this entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can find `fid` under the table name `file_managed`.
2. It is unique id for files. In files you can include images, .txt, .pdf etc extension files.
3. This `fid` is unique for the site and `auto incremented`
4. By using [`file_load($fid)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load/7) function. Where `$fid` is file id.

Fid is only valid for managed files. Files uploaded as unmanaged does not have records in database, so no fid.

Comment: It's `.`, not `)`, if you want to have properly formatted list here.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but you've got to at least get the name of the table right...

Comment: Clive and Molot are right. I suggested an edit to add their observation. Adding these correction, the answer seems complete to me :) Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Once file gets uploaded it stores the record to Database. The fid is file ID of the uploaded file.

Refer [file_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load/7)

Comment: oh, so it is only the incremental id given to the record of the file! Thank you very much

Comment: It's only valid for managed files. Files uploaded as unmanaged does not have records in database, please make it clear in your answer.